# How do I find missing sub-partitions of an index to make main index complete?

Tags: postgresql, index, partitioning

I have a table with many partitions that I wanted to add a new index to. Following [the instructions from Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#:%7E:text=As%20explained%20above,valid%20automatically.%20Example%3A) I created the new index on the main table using `ON ONLY` and then proceeded to create indexes on all the partitions of the table and attach them.

When I got done, I expected the overall index to automatically be marked as valid as per the documentation, however this query was still returning that index (and only that index) as invalid:

```
SELECT *
FROM pg_class,
     pg_index
WHERE pg_index.indisvalid = false
  AND pg_index.indexrelid = pg_class.oid;
```

I'm assuming in my manual creation of the indexes on the partitions that I missed attaching one (I already verified they're there on every partition, including default). Is there a way to have Postgres tell me which partition it's missing?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Pgpartman [has a function](https://github.com/pgpartman/pg_partman/blob/master/doc/pg_partman.md#maintenance-functions) that will fill these partitions in for you: `partition_gap_fill`. Also relevant is the `partition_data_proc` and `partition_data` functions that will actually create partitions and move data from the default partition or other table into the new partitions.

**Original Answer:**

While I was unable to actually figure out a way to get Postgres to tell me which partition was missing, I did come across the `relispartition` flag on the `pg_class` table that I was able to query on and find the partition indexes that I had created but weren't attached to the overall index. Attaching those two partition indexes, made the overall index valid.

Example query to find non-attached indexes:

```
SELECT relname, relpages, reltuples, *
FROM pg_class
WHERE relname ilike '%SOME_PATTERN_IN_ALL_INDEX_NAMES%'
and relispartition is false;
```